# How to connect an application with Facebook?

Tags: python, django, facebook, facebook-fql

The topic may be a bit ambiguous. 
I am writing a Python application. I want to upload it on Facebook as a Facebook application (NOT [Facebook Connect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facebook_Platform#Facebook_Connect)).
But I am having the hardest time figuring out how to implement the features of my application with Facebook.

My application currently uses a MySQL database. Now I want a user of Facebook to use my application and store the results in his/her account. How do I do it? I am afraid to say it but I am a bit scared of all the documentations. So if someone could give me some pointers, I would really really appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a good Facebook library that supports Django, [pyfacebook](http://github.com/sciyoshi/pyfacebook/). There are some examples in that package of how to use it.

And there's no substitute for the actual [Facebook developer documentation](http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Main_Page) - it's written with PHP in mind, but you can use the same API calls via the Python library.

However we can't really give you an entire tutorial via StackOverflow. If you have any specific questions, please ask them.

Comment: +1: Before asking questions, however, read the links supplied in this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Amit, in addition to the links above also have a look at the following links. Also note: You mention you would like to 'upload your app into facebook' you can add your app to facebook, however they DO NOT host it. You will have to host the application on your own server.

1. http://uswaretech.com/blog/2009/02/how-to-build-a-facebook-app-in-django/
2. http://lethain.com/entry/2007/dec/04/two-faced-django-part-1-building-project-exists-si/